# Ansible roles YAML errors

Tags: ansible

I'm try to execute this

```
curl -X PUT 192.168.1.11:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"persistent": {"cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "primaries"}}'
```

And when i do this directly from the shell, it gives me right output

```
curl -X PUT 192.168.1.11:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"persistent": {"cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "primaries"}}'
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "enable" : "primaries"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "transient" : { }
}
```

and here is my ansible shell task

```
- name: Turn off shard reallocation
  shell: "curl -X PUT 192.168.1.11:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"persistent": {"cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "primaries"}}'" 
  register: response
  failed_when: response.stdout.find('"acknowledged":true') == -1
```

and it executes with error

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The offending line appears to be:

- name: Turn off shard reallocation
  shell: "curl -XPUT 192.168.1.11:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"persistent" : {\"cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "primaries"}}'"
                                                                                                          ^ here
```

Comment: Can you use the URI module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html?

Comment: anyway this method fails with quotes

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes inside other double quotes must be escaped.

```
  shell: "curl -X PUT 192.168.1.11:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"persistent\": {\"cluster.routing.allocation.enable\": \"primaries\"}}'"
```

In such cases, you can ease your life and make things more readable by using a [yaml folded scalar block](https://yaml-multiline.info/)

```
  shell: >-
    curl -X PUT 192.168.1.11:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
    -d '{"persistent": {"cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "primaries"}}'
```

Meanwhile have a look at @Matt Schuchard comment and consider using the [`uri` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html) instead of `curl` in `shell`.